# Dymosim OPC server: Items cannot ce acessed by MATLAB

Tags: simulink, opc, dymola

I'm currently using Dymola 2015 and try to run my model on an embedded OPC server. It is a very simpel model, a sine wave with a real output interface.

So far, the following things are working:

1. I can run the embedded OPC no problem
2. The data can be accessed from MatrikonOPC Explorer
3. I can initialize and run the server with MATLABS OPC Toolbox

However, I still have these problems:

1. I can NOT read data from MATLABS OPC Toolbox. When I run the Toolbox inside Simulink and add tags to the OPCRead-Block, it gives the warning "No items defined for the group". When I try to access the data by command line inside MATLAB, it gives me the error message "Unexpected unkown exception from MEX file"
2. When I try to build a bridge to transfer the data from Dysmosim Server to another OPC server with Matrikon's Data Manager, I get the error "Could not create output tag xxxxx.xxx": The server could not be started.

Any help is appreciated.